# XML Signature Generation using IBM SDK 6.0

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I'm having an interesting problem trying to sign a SAML2 Assertion using IBM's JRE 6.0. If I run the code under a Sun JDK, it signs the assertions correctly and the signature verifies. If I run the exact same code under the IBM JRE, the Assertion is created correctly, but the signature won't verify. Again, this is the same code, indeed, as it's running from Jetty, it's the exact same Jetty config and WAR file as well. I have two instances of Jetty running on different ports with different JREs but pointing to the same Jetty home. The signatures generated under the Sun JRE validate, but those generated under the IBM JRE do not. I'm frankly stumped and am running out of things to try, so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, figured this out. As it turns out, the Sun implementation of XML Dsig is more tolerant than Xerces/XML Security and IBM's implementation. There was a mix of DOM1 and DOM2 calls that were causing problems and the way URIs were dereferenced also caused issues. Replacing all DOM1 calls (DOM calls with no namespace) with DOM2 calls and setting the id information on the DOMSignContext solved the problem and it works under both JVMs now.

Comment: Hey could you further explain what you did in your comment? Its the Xerces Implmentation that has to be changed right? Whats the best way to do that? I tried changing the Parent_ClassLaoader but I got Servlet classpath errors. So I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: Basically I just made sure that every DOM call was one that uses a namespace value. So instead of Document.createElement(), I used Document.createElementNS(). By making sure that everything had a namespace defined it cleared up the errors. There's no need to change Xerces implementations, just don't mix DOM1 (not namespace aware) and DOM2+ (namespace aware) calls on the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few years late, but I'm going to answer this myself. The problem was a mix of DOM1 (non-namespace aware) and DOM2+ (namespace aware) calls. By shifting everything to namespace aware DOM2+ calls, the problem went away.